# Counting reactions on discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a poll bot, and now I want to know how to count the reactions and find winner answer, I've tried a lot but I can't manage to do it. Does anyone knows?

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="¡Es momento de tomar una encuesta!", colour=discord.Colour(0x3e038c))
embed.add_field(name='Autor de la encuesta', value=f'{ctx.author}')
embed.add_field(name='Pregunta:', value=f'{pregunta}')
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
await msg.add_reaction(str(''))
await msg.add_reaction(str(''))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you want you only need to check the `length` of the `message.reactions` parameter.

Example:

```
from discord.utils import get

async def check_winner(self, ctx, messageid: int):
    # ...
    # Some code here

    message = await ctx.fetch_message(messageid)
    reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji='your emoji here')
    num_reactions = reaction.count

    # More code here
    # ...
```

In the command to check the winner of your poll you will first need to retrieve the **message_id** of the poll, then pass it to your command as parameter so you can retrieve the `message` object and find the **reactions** attached to it.

References:

- [fetch_message()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message)
- [message.reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.reactions)
- [discord.utils.get()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#discord.utils.get)

Comment: `len(message.reactions)` would just return how many different reactions there is, not the most used reaction

Comment: It gives me an atribute error `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'`. I have to do something more?

Comment: Try using `ctx.fetch_message()`. The `bot` object does not have that method.